# Using group by and count with laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a Forum and Forum Response Model with following database tables:

```
forum.id

forum_response.id
forum_response.forum_id
forum_response.user_id
forum_response.text
```

The Forum Model relationship is:

```
public function responses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(ForumResponse::class, 'forum__responses');
}
```

and the Forum Response relationship:

```
public function Forum()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Forum::class);
}
```

I would like to get the number of unique responses for a specific Forum, grouped by the user_id. I have tried the following `return $this->hasMany(ForumResponse::class)->groupBy('user_id')->count();` but this is returning a higher value than I'm expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Even though, I feel you have something wrong in your structure. But for now, you have an error in your relationships. Just change belongsToMany to hasMany

change this

```
public function responses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(ForumResponse::class, 'forum__responses');
}
```

to this

```
public function responses()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ForumResponse::class, 'forum__responses');
}
```